# How to connect to xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a button in java code:

```
Button next = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.Button1);
```

I want every time that the button get clicked I to update string.xml in this form:

```
<string-array name="steps">
    <item >step1</item>
    <item >step2</item>
    <item >step3</item>
 </string-array>
```

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Check my answer below, and let me know if it helped to you ;)

Comment: You don't connect to files. You open them.

Comment: as long as people understand what you get the idea that you are trying to say this is what matter , it don't matter the fault or grammar or any thing

Comment: So is not what you want @YousSef ?

Comment: @YousSef have a look on my answer. I think it will help you . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set the text of a textview using the Array and the index you want 
So for example you want to set a textview named t1 to index one in your oncreate

```
 t1.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.steps)[1]);
```